# ARKit Perspective Rendering

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I am working on a perspective problem with ARKit that I encountered in one of my projects.

I explain you: in the photo below, I display a 3D model along the lane, there are small 3D boxes every 2 meters. Then, I place indicators at the level of these boxes, as you can see on the photo, the 3D models shift and do not seem to be in the right place when we move away from the boxes.

I would like to know if this comes from ARKit or simply from my way of displaying this model. Knowing that the 3D model generated with Blender is flat (horizontal). 
I suppose this comes from the detection of the marker to anchor the 3D model, the transformation matrix must be slightly inclined and must distort the perspective on long 3D models.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: If your markers are SCNNodes can’t you just add the model as a child of the marker?

Comment: @JoshRobbins I have only one marker to render the 3D model. The markers that you see along the lane are just for me. (an indicator every 2 meters, it allows me to check the metric)