# Bad scaling rendering ARKit

Tags: ios, rendering, scenekit, arkit

I'm working on perspective tests with ARKit and SceneKit. The idea is to improve 3D rendering when displaying a flat 3D model on the ground. I had already opened a ticket to another perspective problem that is almost solved. ([ARKit Perspective Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377892/arkit-perspective-rendering?noredirect=1#comment89803924_51377892))

However, I noticed after my multitudes tests / 3D display, that sometimes when I anchor a 3D model, the size of it can differ... (width and length)
I usually display a 3D model that is 16 meters long and 1.5 meters wide. You can well imagine that this distorts my rendering. 
I don't know why my display may differ in terms of 3D model size.
Maybe it's from the tracking and my test environment.

Below is the code I use to add my 3D model to the scene:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
    let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage
    let imageAnchorPosition = imageAnchor.transform.columns.3
    print("Image detected")

    let modelName = "couloirV2"
    //let modelName = "lamp"
    guard let object = VirtualObject
        .availableObjects
        .filter({ $0.modelName == modelName })
        .first else { fatalError("Cannot get model \(modelName)") }

    print("Loading \(object)...")

    self.sceneView.prepare([object], completionHandler: { _ in
        self.updateQueue.async {
            // Translate the object's position to the reference node position.
            object.position.x = imageAnchorPosition.x
            object.position.y = imageAnchorPosition.y
            object.position.z = imageAnchorPosition.z

            // Save the initial y value for slider handler function
            self.tmpYPosition = object.position.y

            // Match y node's orientation
            object.orientation.y = node.orientation.y
            print("Adding object to the scene")

            // Prepare the object
            object.load()

            // Show origin axis
            object.showObjectOrigin()


            // Translate on z axis to match perfectly with image detected.
            var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
            translation.columns.3.z += Float(referenceImage.physicalSize.height / 2)
            object.simdTransform = matrix_multiply(object.simdTransform, translation)

            self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(object)
            self.virtualObjectInteraction.selectedObject = object
            self.sceneView.addOrUpdateAnchor(for: object)
        }
    })
}
```